# Prove an inequality or find the global optimum solution

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

I have an expression on $x$ as follows (from my friend).

$f(x)=x^4-2 a d x^3-2 b d x^3-2 c d x^3-2 d x^3+a^2 d^2 x^2+b^2 d^2 x^2+c^2 d^2 x^2+4 a d^2 x^2+2 a b d^2 x^2+3 b d^2 x^2+2 a c d^2 x^2+3 b c d^2 x^2+3 c d^2 x^2-a b x^2-a c x^2-b c x^2+2 a b d x^2+2 a c d x^2+2 b c d x^2+2 d x^2-x^2-2 a^2 d^3 x-b^2 d^3 x-b c^2 d^3 x-c^2 d^3 x-3 a b d^3 x-b^2 c d^3 x-3 a c d^3 x-2 a b c d^3 x-2 b c d^3 x-2 a b^2 d^2 x-2 a c^2 d^2 x-2 b c^2 d^2 x-4 a d^2 x-2 a^2 b d^2 x-2 a b d^2 x-2 b d^2 x-2 a^2 c d^2 x-2 b^2 c d^2 x-2 a c d^2 x-4 a b c d^2 x-4 b c d^2 x-2 c d^2 x+a b^2 d x+a c^2 d x+b c^2 d x+2 a d x+a^2 b d x+a b d x+b d x+a^2 c d x+b^2 c d x+a c d x+2 a b c d x+2 b c d x+c d x+2 a^2 d^3+2 a b^2 d^3+2 b^2 c^2 d^3+2 a c^2 d^3+2 a b c^2 d^3+2 b c^2 d^3+2 a^2 b d^3+2 a b d^3+2 a^2 c d^3+2 a b^2 c d^3+2 b^2 c d^3+2 a c d^3+8 a b c d^3-a^2 d^2-a b^2 d^2-b^2 c^2 d^2-a c^2 d^2-a b c^2 d^2-b c^2 d^2-a^2 b d^2-a b d^2-a^2 c d^2-a b^2 c d^2-b^2 c d^2-a c d^2+4 a^2 b c d^2-12 a b c d^2+4 b c d^2+a^2 b c-2 a b c+b c-4 a^2 b c d+8 a b c d-4 b c d$

where $a\geqslant b+1, b\geqslant c,  b\geqslant1, c\geqslant0, 0\leqslant d \leqslant1$ and $a,b,c$ are integers.

I would like to prove that $f(x)>0$ or $\min f(x)>0$ when
$$x\geqslant \frac{1}{2}\left(d(2a+b+c)+\sqrt{d^2(2a+b+c)^2+8a(b+c)(1-2d)}\right),$$

When I used **Lingo**, it only found a local minimum (3.6..) instead of the global minimum (even though I chose the option Global Solve).

```
min=(-a^2)*d^2+2*a^2*d^3-a*d^2*b-a^2*d^2*b+2*a*d^3*b+2*a^2*d^3*b-a*d^2*b^2+2*a*d^3*b^2-a*d^2*c-
a^2*d^2*c+2*a*d^3*c+2*a^2*d^3*c+b*c-2*a*b*c+a^2*b*c-4*d*b*c+8*a*d*b*c-4*a^2*d*b*c+
4*d^2*b*c-12*a*d^2*b*c+4*a^2*d^2*b*c+8*a*d^3*b*c-d^2*b^2*c-a*d^2*b^2*c+2*d^3*b^2*c+
2*a*d^3*b^2*c-a*d^2*c^2+2*a*d^3*c^2-d^2*b*c^2-a*d^2*b*c^2+2*d^3*b*c^2+2*a*d^3*b*c^2-
d^2*b^2*c^2+2*d^3*b^2*c^2+2*a*d*x-4*a*d^2*x-2*a^2*d^3*x+d*b*x+a*d*b*x+a^2*d*b*x-2*d^2*b*x-
2*a*d^2*b*x-2*a^2*d^2*b*x-3*a*d^3*b*x+a*d*b^2*x-2*a*d^2*b^2*x-d^3*b^2*x+d*c*x+a*d*c*x+
a^2*d*c*x-2*d^2*c*x-2*a*d^2*c*x-2*a^2*d^2*c*x-3*a*d^3*c*x+2*d*b*c*x+2*a*d*b*c*x-4*d^2*b*c*x-
4*a*d^2*b*c*x-2*d^3*b*c*x-2*a*d^3*b*c*x+d*b^2*c*x-2*d^2*b^2*c*x-d^3*b^2*c*x+a*d*c^2*x-
2*a*d^2*c^2*x-d^3*c^2*x+d*b*c^2*x-2*d^2*b*c^2*x-d^3*b*c^2*x-x^2+2*d*x^2+4*a*d^2*x^2+
a^2*d^2*x^2-a*b*x^2+2*a*d*b*x^2+3*d^2*b*x^2+2*a*d^2*b*x^2+d^2*b^2*x^2-a*c*x^2+2*a*d*c*x^2+
3*d^2*c*x^2+2*a*d^2*c*x^2-b*c*x^2+2*d*b*c*x^2+3*d^2*b*c*x^2+d^2*c^2*x^2-2*d*x^3-2*a*d*x^3-
2*d*b*x^3-2*d*c*x^3+x^4;
x >= 1/2*(d*(2*a + b + c) + @SQRT((d)^2*(2*a + b + c)^2 + 8*a*(b + c)*(1 - 2*d))); 
a >= b + 1;
b >= c;
b >= 1;
c >= 0;
d >= 0;
d <= 1;
@GIN(a);
@GIN(b);
@GIN(c);
```

```
  Local optimal solution found.
  Objective value:                              3.646110
  Objective bound:                              3.646110
  Infeasibilities:                              0.000000
  Extended solver steps:                               0
  Total solver iterations:                            21
  Elapsed runtime seconds:                          0.14

  Model Class:                                     MINLP

  Total variables:                      5
  Nonlinear variables:                  5
  Integer variables:                    3

  Total constraints:                    8
  Nonlinear constraints:                2

  Total nonzeros:                      18
  Nonlinear nonzeros:                   9



                                Variable           Value        Reduced Cost
                                       A        2.000000            0.000000
                                       D       0.1741100            0.000000
                                       B        1.000000            0.000000
                                       C        0.000000            0.000000
                                       X        2.107574            0.000000

                                     Row    Slack or Surplus      Dual Price
                                       1        3.646110           -1.000000
                                       2        0.000000           -14.59492
                                       3        0.000000           -5.918372
                                       4        1.000000            0.000000
                                       5        0.000000           -13.40245
                                       6        0.000000           -5.672014
                                       7       0.1741100            0.000000
                                       8       0.8258900            0.000000
```

Can I assert that the local optimum solution $3.646110$ is the global optimum solution? Or is their difference so small that it is enough to demonstrate $f > 0$? Or is it possible that this expression does not have a global minimum value? I originally intended to use *Mathematica* for calculations, but unfortunately, there are no corresponding results. Please see the link below.

- [How to estimate whether the objective expression has a global minimum value?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285667/how-to-estimate-whether-the-objective-expression-has-a-global-minimum-value)

---

In the original problem, $f(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

$$A:=\left(
             \begin{array}{cccc}
               d(b+1) & 0 & (1-d)b & 1-d  \\
               0 & d(a+b) & (1-d)b & (1-d)a \\
               (1-d)a & (1-d)c & d(a+c) & 0 \\
               1-d& (1-d)c & 0 & d(c+1)  \\
             \end{array}
           \right).$$

Comment: What is an original problem?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg This problem was formulated by my friend. The specific background is derived from graph spectra theory.  I'm also interested in this problem and would like to explore possible strategies for a human proof. See the new edit.

Comment: This is not an exercise from a book or a competition problem, so its solution is open-ended, and it's even possible to find counterexamples.

Comment: It seems BW (Buffalo Way) kills it.

Comment: @River Li Can you provide more details? Thank you in advance, as it may take up valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Mathematica`, after reducing the constraints:

```
Reduce[{a >= b + 1, b >= c, b >= 1, c >= 0, d >= 0, d <= 1}, c]
```

> (a == 2 && b == 1 && 0 <= d <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1) || 
> (a > 2 && 1 <= b <= -1 + a && 0 <= d <= 1 && 0 <= c <= b)

and after verifying that:

```
emin = ((2 a + b + c) d + Sqrt[(2 a + b + c)^2 d^2 + 8 a (b + c) (1 - 2 d)]) / 2;
cons = {a >= 2, 1 <= b <= a - 1, 0 <= c <= b, 0 <= d <= 1};
NMinimize[{emin, cons}, {a, b, c, d}]
```

> {2., {a -> 2., b -> 1., c -> 6.10647 * 10^-8, d -> 1.22195 * 10^-7}}

it's possible to write:

```
A = {{d (b + 1), 0, (1 - d) b, 1 - d},
     {0, d (a + b), (1 - d) b, (1 - d) a},
     {(1 - d) a, (1 - d) c, d (a + c), 0},
     {1 - d, (1 - d) c, 0, d (c + 1)}};

f = Det[A - e IdentityMatrix[4]];

cons = {a >= 2, 1 <= b <= a - 1, 0 <= c <= b, 0 <= d <= 1, e >= 2, e >= emin};

NMinimize[{f, cons}, {a, b, c, d, e}]
```

> {2.59802, {a -> 2., b -> 1., c -> 1., d -> 0.795932, e -> 3.37098}}

that is, `f` is positive in `cons`, as we wanted to prove.

Comment: *Mathematica* provides the solution, but it gives the following warning message: `NMinimize::incst: NMinimize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constraints {1-a+b<=0,-b+c<=0,1/2 ((Times[<<2>>]+b+c) d+Sqrt[Times[<<4>>]+Times[<<2>>]])-e<=0}. The initial region specified may not contain any feasible points. Changing the initial region or specifying explicit initial points may provide a better solution.` Does this mean that the solution is a local optimum rather than a global optimum?

Comment: Nice! I noticed that you set `e` to be less than or equal to 10. Does this mean that `e ` greater than or equal to 10 does not need to be considered? Was this setting of 10 random?

Comment: I have noticed that  based on the constraint `e >= ((2a + b + c) d + Sqrt[(2a + b + c)^2 d^2 + 8a (b + c) (1 - 2d)])/2`,  `e` can be very large positive real numbers. In this case, is it appropriate to constrain `e` to be less than a constant? Could there be a contradiction? You further narrowed down the range of `a ` ($a\le 10$) as well. It would be perfect if we could prove that there won't be a minimum value outside of these special range.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146302/discussion-between-licheng-and-tem).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your Mathematica approach is excellent. It seems that the distance of $2.59802$ from $0$ is quite significant, which is very inspiring for seeking artificial mathematical methods.